# Raise source error("nothing to repeat") when trying to convert multiple regex expressions to int values

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex expressions parse the numbers in strings with formats like this:

```
"R5+2-3"
```

Where the number after "R" is the total number of tests, the number after "+" is the number of positive tests, and the number after "-" is the number of negative tests. I'm trying to get the number of total tests, positive tests, and negative tests stored as integer values. I've tried using the following code:

```
ttl = 0
pos = 0
neg = 0
for matchttl in re.findall('R(\d+)', s):
    ttl = ttl + int(matchttl)
for matchpos in re.findall('+(\d+)', s):
    pos = pos + int(matchpos) 
for matchneg in re.findall('-(\d+)', s):
    neg = neg + int(matchneg)
```

Each expression works on its own, but when I use 2 or more expressions I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users...", line 668, in _parse
  raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `+` has a special meaning in a regex.

Comment: @MichaelButscher completely overlooked that, thanks very much! Would I then enclose the "+" with [ ]?

Comment: Escape it right? Test your regex at regexr.com